# Derivative over scalar field with respect to fixed point proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Prove there is no such scalar field that $f '(a;y) >0$ for fixed point $a$ and every non-zero vector $y$.

I posted this question but some of you pointed out that it is not clear.

So, $f ' (a;y)$ is a derivative of at point "$a$" with respect to vector $y$ in scalar field,

where $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

I tried to prove this by letting  $y=-a$, and usual definition of derivative at point "$a$" is

$f(a+hy)-f(a)/h$ as $h$ goes to $0$. So if I let $y=-a$, it follows that $f(ah)-f(a)/h$ as $h$ goes to $0$.

And, I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f'(a;y)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ in the direction  $y$, you have $f'(a;-y) = -f'(a;y)$

Comment: How can it be ? Can you explain why since we are looking for a proof